# Why can I never get the second conditional to be true?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm a beginner to python and I was wondering why I cannot get the elif conditional to return true and execute the code. Whatever I try and input for Choice I always get "hello world" printing rather than "I rule the world"

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello " + name)
choice = input('option 1: say Hello World or Option 2: say I rule the world?')

if choice == "option 1" or "1":
     counter = 0
     while counter < 50:
          print("hello world")
          counter += 1

          
elif choice == "option 2" or "2":          
     counter = 0
     while counter < 50:
          print("I rule the world")
          counter += 1
```

Comment: You should put more relevant tags in your questions, `python` will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

This should work since your if statements were off. You should do lowercase to choice to compare as well.

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello " + name)
choice = input('option 1: say Hello World or Option 2: say I rule the world?')

if (choice.lower() == "option 1") or(choice =="1") :
     counter = 0
     while counter < 50:
          print("hello world")
          counter += 1

          
elif (choice.lower() == "option 2") or (choice =="2"):          
     counter = 0
     while counter < 50:
          print("I rule the world")
          counter += 1
```

Comment: It is a fix, but not an explanation of what went wrong, and **why**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is the following line:

```
if choice == "option 1" or "1":
```

Here you are not looking whether `choice` is "option 1" *or* "1", but if it is equal to "option 1", or the string value "1", **which is evaluated to** `true`, thus, you always get the first loops.

It should look like:

```
if ((choice == "option 1") or (choice == "1")):
```

The same goes for the line of the elif:

```
elif ((choice == "option 2") or (choice == "2")):
```

If you run the following code:

```
if "1":
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

you will see that the output is `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! I understand now

Comment: Well done for explaining why there’s a problem, but there’s absolutely no need for all those ( ) in the `if` Or `elif` statement.

Comment: @barny I know, but I'm using it for better clarity, especially when this question is around this exact error!

Comment: Maybe you should explain that to the OP too “these brackets are for emphasis but are completely unnecessary” - but TBH I think it’s clearer _not_to show them.

Comment: @barny It removes any ambiguity possible in this situation. It may look "cleaner" not using brackets (and many python developers will prefer it), but it can be very confusing for new programmers and in some **other** programming languages, counter intuitive (or even result in undefined behavior).

Comment: @camilochapman You should accept an answer to close the question.